# How to instantiate an object and pass it to a method within the declaration of a "using" block

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I am using an external class which implements IDisposable and an external method which populates an instance of that class.

I am looking for a neat way to encapsulate the disposable object in a "using" statement but can't work out the syntax.

Let's say the class is ...

```
class Something : IDisposable
```

And the function is ...

```
void PopulateSomething(Something theObject)
```

I could do this ...

```
Something myObject = new Something();
PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
x = myObject.SomeNumber;
myObject.Dispose();
```

or I could also do this ...

```
Something myObject = new Something();
using(myObject)
{
    x = myObject.SomeNumber;
}
```

but neither of the above are great because after disposal I could stupidly write something like this

```
x = myObject.SomeNumber; // which will throw an exception
```

I suppose I could do this ...

```
using(Something myObject = new Something())
{
    PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

But I would like to believe something like the following is possible but I can't figure out the syntax...

```
using (Something myObject => PopulateSomethingObject(myObject = new Something()))
{
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

I guess it's sort of a theoretical question because I don't really have a problem here but I am curious to know if it is possible. i.e. Instantiate the object and pass it to a method within the declaration of the "using(...){} block.

Comment: Are you able to edit `PopulateSomethingObject`

Comment: Nope. It's in an external library.

Comment: I want to achieve basically what the second-last example does but on one line. No real reason for it, it guess!

Comment: How about wrapping the *PopulateSomethingObject* method in to another method that directly creates *new Something()* and populates it and returns it?

Comment: @bit That would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you could do

```
private Something CreateAndPopulate()
{
    var myObject = new Something();
    PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
    return myObject;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
using (var myObject = CreateAndPopulate())
{
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

**Update1**
One other way to do that could be by writing an Extension for `Something` like

```
public static class SomethingExtension
{
    public static Something Populate(this Something someObj, Action<Something> actionToPopulate)
    {
        actionToPopulate.Invoke(someObj);
        return someObj;
    }
}
```

And then using it in a single line like:

```
using (var myObject = new Something().Populate(PopulateSomethingObject))
{
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

**Update2**
Fianlly, one line way to do it could look complicated

```
using (var myObject = new Func<Something>(() =>
                    {
                        var myNewObject = new Something();
                        PopulateSomethingObject(myNewObject);
                        return myNewObject;
                    }).Invoke())
{
    //x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

Comment: It does the job. But what I really wanted was a way to instantiate and populate in one line of code rather than two. A separate function seems to be adding even more code. 
I would have thought there was some way to do this with a lambda.

Comment: @MarcusCunningham Check out the other way to do it.

Comment: "one line way to do it" looks complicated because it takes four lines. I would take OP's last example over this "one-liner" any day (I'm sure you would too :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , I agree! Just multiple lines crunched into one!

Comment: The extension method wins the day!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the signature of the `PopulateSomething` method, which prevents you from creating and using `Something` objects in a single expression. Since `PopulateSomething`'s return type is `void`, it must be used as a statement, not as an expression.

Your last approach that compiles is pretty good:

```
using (Something myObject = new Something()) {
    PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

In fact, it is similar to the pattern used with database connections, when the object created inside `using` undergoes some additional configuration before use:

```
using (conn = factory.CreateConnection()) {
    // Do more things to conn before its first use.
    conn.ConnectionString = "...";
    conn.Open();
    ... // Use conn here
}
```

If you would like to avoid the call to `PopulateSomethingObject` inside `using`, make a factory method returning `Something`, like this:

```
private static Something GetAndConfigure() {
    Something res = new Something();
    PopulateSomethingObject(res);
    return res;
}
```

Now you can write

```
using (Something myObject = GetAndConfigure()) {
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(Something myObject = new Something())
{
    PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

This is the correct usage of a USING block. You create the instance inside the brackets.

If you really didnt want to dispose the object then you shouldnt be using the USING in the first place.

Comment: @Rob I know, he posted multiple ways to do the same thing. Im just pointing out that this is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should put only objects inside `using`. 
And for my point of view the idea is not so good. I see two parts of code - the first path creates the object, and the second - processes it. And you try to mix the first part with the second. I think that the last option is less readable than

```
using(Something myObject = new Something())
{
    PopulateSomethingObject(myObject);
    x = myObject.SomeNumber();
}
```

Comment: I totally agree. In my case the external library (which happens to be Open CV via emgu .NET wrapper) changed the method signatures with a new release.